# Wants to hide list item based on condition using SharePoint default search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, search, sharepoint-addin, search-results

I have two list items in SharePoint list.

1.approval_status='pending' and title='Test'

2.approval-status='Approved' and title='Test'

if user search item based on search title field(e.g.Test), I want to show approval_status='Approved' items only if  approval_status='pending' i don't want to show the item in SharePoint search.

Comment: If you use the out of the box item or document approval this happens by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, you can create a query rule or result source which modifies the query to exclude “pending” results.

Change the search query and append the query text like the following format in the Query text box to filter out the “pending” results.

```
-<managed property>:<value>
```

[Manage query rules in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-query-rules)

[Configure result sources for search in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-result-sources-for-search)

[Building search queries in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint)